# How can I keep record (or see) of what value was given by the distribution each time the process took place?

Tags: anylogic

I have beeen constructing a model in Anylogic in the last weeks, and I am currently simulating the time a truck takes to deliver its products, so I used a delay for this in which different parameters are multiplied to several distributions. Is there any was I can keep track of the value of the distribution each time the process takes place. The following is in example:

normal(2, 8, 4.67, 1.96)*DropSize

The DropSize is my parameter, but I wish to know what value was generated for the normal distribution, and keep track of this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, several ways (as usual with AnyLogic :-) ). Here is one:

create a collection of type ArrayList:

[image]

Then, create a function that draws the random value, stores it in the collection and returns it as below:

[image]

Last, replace your code creating the random value with calling that function. Now, whenever you pull a value from the distribution, it is also stored in the collection.

cheers